# SRAM 22 Road 'Group'?

Tags: sram, groupsets

I'm building up a new road bike. I had thought to try out an SRAM component system. However, looking for RIVAL 22 parts, I can't find the whole set in one place, and I'm unsure about the attendant bits (the little couplers for the hydraulic brake lines, for example). I'll go online and find the crankset, but not the chain; or the brakes and derailleur but not the crankset. The SRAM website is kind of a disaster, too. So, I looked at the Shimano site and there's a diagram that shows all the components and all the bits for each level of equipment; one can write down the parts needed. And, I look online and there's the whole group for sale, allowing a choice between possible cassettes, crank arm lengths, etc. Am I missing something here, or is SRAM just less organized than Shimano?

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing they have to what you're looking for are their "Compatibility Map" documents, which show what's compatible with what in the manner you would be interested in seeing if you were building up a complete bike. However, they split them between brakes and drivetrain. You can find them on their public-facing support pages.
[image]
[image]

For brake adapters, it shows on each product page what adapters it comes with. I believe with SRAM, flat mount caliper/adapter screws are not included and have to be purchased separately (what you need depends on your chainstay thickness and is covered in the service manuals).

You are right that SRAM is oblique about what hose fittings and hose come with each product. I believe the packaged-together shifter and caliper sets come with everything needed, but I don't have simple answers for the solo "replacement" type parts, some of which don't seem to show up on their site. If memory serves, those can be pretty minimal about what comes in the box, so yes they may need separately purchased fittings.